# Display only unique records in django model admin form other model

Tags: mysql, django, django-admin

I have a model called A with following fields

```
class A(models.Model):
     f_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
     l_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
     email = models.EmailField(unique=False)
     phone = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
```

Now I'm creating another model B from model A

```
class B(A):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

admin class for B is

```
class BAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     list_display = ('email','first_name', 'last_name', 'phone')
```

I want to display only distinct email in model B from model A in admin site?

Note: I don't want disturb model A but i want to get unique email records in BAdmin

for example records in model A

1. test2@xyz.com  test2  xxx
2. test2@xyz.com  test2  xxx
3. test3@zxc.com  test3 xyz

I want to display unique records in model B admin as

1. test2@xyz.com  test2  xxx
2. test3@zxc.com  test3 xyz

I tried by writing queryset in BAdmin by

```
def queryset(self, request):
    qs = super(BAdmin, self).queryset(request)
    qs = qs.distinct('email')

    return qs
```

when i write above , I am getting DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend(MySQL) error is there another way to to display unique records in model B?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `queryset()` method in `ModelAdmin` class to filter what you want:

```
class BAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'phone')

    def queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(BAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        qs = qs.distinct('email')

        return qs
```

Comment: I tried above but i got an error DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend. Currently I'm using MySQL as Database.

Comment: It only works with postgresql. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#distinct

Comment: Then how i can get with MySQL Database?